# java: creating jars that expect configuration files

Tags: java, configuration-files

I wish to make a jar file that requires any project using it to have some config.xml file in their META-INF directory.

If I reference the directory using `getClass().getResource("META-INF/config.xml")` during runtime, will it detect the file on the classpath?

if not what is the best practices surrounding this requirement?

Please, thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? I think it shall be OK.

Comment: In addition to @Leos - just make sure the two jars use the same classloader. Especially when deploying it to an Application Server.